# Get x and y from index in pixel array

Tags: java, arrays, pixel

So I have an array of pixels to represent an image.  I'm currently trying to get an x and y value from an element of the pixel array, but I can only get the x successfully.

My current code:

```
 public int[] draw(int[] pixels, int index, int xOffs, int yOffs) {

    int x0 = index % width;
    int y0 = (index * x0) / height;

    for (int y = y0 * size; y < y0 * size + size; y++) {
        int yPix = y + yOffs - (size * y0);
        if (yPix < 0 || yPix >= Game.height) continue;

        for (int x = x0 * size; x < x0 * size + size; x++) {
            int xPix = x + xOffs - (size * x0);
            if (xPix < 0 || xPix >= Game.width) continue;

            int src = this.pixels[x + y * width];
            pixels[xPix + yPix * Game.width] = src;
        }
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

x0 returns the correct value, e.g if the index was 4, then it would return 0.
y0 always returns 0.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a sprite sheet using pixel manipulation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but I think `int y0 = (index * x0) / height;` should be `int y0 = index/width;`.

PS. why are you adding `(y0 * size)` to `y` and the subtracting it again in `yPix`, it seems unnecessary  and also it makes your code a little bit unreadable.